# Can't find differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. only supports binding to Iterables while reading & parsing data from JSON file

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, dom, ionic4

he problem is related to Ionic Angular. Reading parsing and displaying the data appropriately as per my need.

I have a cdata.json file and from that I'm reading the data, through a service class file and passing it onto the front end html file to be displayed :

c_data.json

```
    {
    "categories": [
    {
        "c_id": "C01",
        "c_name": "Medical Supplies[non-prescription]",
        "c_description": "Medical supplies needed during general cases of illness, like 
        diahorrea, head-ache, weakness & fatigue, sleeplessness, heat-rashes, allergies etc.",
        "icon": "pill",
        "profilePic": ""
    },
    {
        "c_id": "C02",
        "c_name": "Medical Supplies[prescription]",
        "c_description": "Medical supplies needed during more complicated cases of chronic 
        illnesses that require doctors supervision, prescription and prescribed medicine. You 
        would be required to upload necessary documents to either file a requirement or 
        request the same from another member.",
        "icon": "pill",
        "profilePic": ""
    },
    ..... ..
    .... .
    ...
    .

    ]}
```

the injectable service class file:

```
    export class CategoryData {

    data: any;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient)
    {

    }

    loadCategories(): any
    {
         if (this.data)
         {
              return of(this.data);
         } 
         else 
         {
              return this.http.get('assets/data/cat_data.json')
              .pipe(map(this.processData, this));
         }
    }

    processData(data: any) {

    this.data = data;

    // loop through each day in the schedule
    this.data.categories.forEach((category: any) => {
    if (category)
    {
        console.log('Fetched');
    }
    else
    {
       console.log('Incapable to fetch category data');
    }

    });

    return this.data;
    }

    getCategories()
    {
       return this.loadCategories();
    }
    }
```

Markup of the htrml where I'm trying to bind this:

```
<ion-grid fixed>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-md="6" *ngFor="let cat of categories">
        <ion-card class="category-card">
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-item detail="false" lines="none" class="category-item" routerLink="/app/tabs/categories/category-details/{{cat.id}}">
              <ion-avatar slot="start">
                <img [src]="cat.profilePic" [alt]="cat.name + ' profile picture'">
              </ion-avatar>
              <ion-label>
                <h2>{{cat.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{cat.title}}</p>
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-card-header>

          <ion-card-content>

            <ion-list lines="none">

              <ion-item detail="false" routerLink="/app/tabs/categories/category-details/{{cat.c_id}}">
                <ion-label>
                  <h3>About {{cat.c_name}}</h3>
                </ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

respective typescript:

```
export class CategoryListPage
{

  categories: any;

  constructor(public catData: CategoryData) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter()
  {
    this.catData.getCategories().subscribe((categories: any) => {

      this.categories = categories;

    });
  }

}
```

The error message in Console:

***Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:4841)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31913)***

The categories data is fetched just fine if I inspect. {categories : Array(9)} and as you expand it, the data is there.
So what's wrong here. This is not a iterable? What means?

As alternative what I tried:

In service class:

```
cdata:any[];
{

  .....
  ....
  
  
  ..
  .
  ...
  .

  processData(data: any):Observable<any> {

    this.data = data;

    // loop through each day in the schedule
    this.data.categories.forEach((category: any) => {
      if (category)
      {
        console.log('Fetched');
        this.cdata.push(category);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('Incapable to fetch category data');
      }

    });

    return this.data;
  }

  getCategories()
  {
    return this.loadCategories();
  }
}
```

In the .ts file of the html markup:

```
export class CategoryListPage
{

  categories: any[];

  constructor(public catData: CategoryData) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter()
  {
    this.catData.getCategories().subscribe((categories: any) => {

      this.categories = categories;

    });
  }

}
```

This throws errors. like, could not implement method .push() of undefined. And many more...

Tx in anticipation

Comment: this.http.get returns an object. The reason why you have such a difficulty understanding your problem is because you put any everywhere. Put actual types instead and you'll understand

Comment: where, specifically ??   @misha130

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks like your categories is an array. So the code should define an *array* of any: `any[]`.

Something like this:

```
export class CategoryListPage
{

  categories: any[];

  constructor(public catData: CategoryData) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter()
  {
    this.catData.getCategories().subscribe((categories: any[]) => {

      this.categories = categories;

    });
  }

}
```

An array would make it 'iterable' as defined by your error message.

Comment: Hi @DeborahK I edited the codebehind of the category-list page as per suggestion. I have now, categories:any[]=[]; as the variable at the class level.
But I cannot use, catData.getCategories<any[]>     it gives error --> expected 0 type arguments but got 1. It is because of the getCategories() method which simply returns loadCategories() .....  

Hope you understand, how the case-scenario is ...
all the problem is here in this line -->  this.data.forEach((category: Category) => of the processData() method of the category-data.ts service ...

Comment: I created this stackblitz--->  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6h9vwa

Currently it shows  can't find package rxJS  [although it is there]
If somehow someone can get this one running and just bind and show the data on the category tab-page, that'll suffice for me. That'd be enough!         @deborahk

Comment: I haven't used ionic. Does it require Angular v5? (Angular is currently on v12) Also, it looks like it's trying to install RxJS 7. AFAIK, RxJS 7 is not yet compatible with Angular v12 (and definitely not compatible with Angular v5).

Comment: And there was an error in the above code. The getCategories should not have a generic argument after it. I corrected it above.

Comment: I see, i'll try downgrading the package version for rxJS, or upgrade the angular packages to 12 .... let's see, if that would work. annoying thing is, as of now, I can't get it going on my actual project, nor in the stackblitz simulation, @DeborahK   thanks for the hints Deborah, I'll keep you posted how this progresses,

Comment: Another option, if the issue is not with the ionic part of the code, create a default Angular stackblitz and put the problematic code in there with a sample UI to view the result (or just a console.log().

Comment: yep. makes sense, in most simple straight way see if the angular stuff works [excluding the ionic thing]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't specify the object type. First create a data model according to your json return result and use that data object type instead of any type.

Example:-

```
export class category{
    c_id: string;
    c_name: string ;
    c_description: string[];
    icon: string;
    profilePic: string
}

data: category[];

processData(data) {

    this.data = data;

// loop through each day in the schedule
    this.data.categories.forEach((category: category) => {
    if (category)
    {
        console.log('Fetched');
    }
    else
    {
       console.log('Incapable to fetch category data');
    }

    });

    return this.data;
    }
```

Comment: @hash-dew               I used 'any' originally since it is a dynamic type to make my job easier.

btw, I tried ur thing. Now I have 2 errors on code,

this line  -->  this.data.categories.forEach((category: any)
property categories does not exist on type Category[].
As alternate I straightaway tried this.data.forEach(.......    since my c_data.json has only 1 array after all. It gives me error --->   this.data.forEach is not a function

Comment: Can you share your code in stackblitz? So I can take a look and let you know what to do. Maybe the model is not match with your data.

Comment: ok, will try n do that     @hash-dew    will notify

Comment: take a look at this -->  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kjal1e             @hash-dew

you MAY need to do quite some tidying up there(the dependencies and paths for the references in the TS files)    I apologize; not used to creating stackblitzes for ionic. but whole portion of whatever I have in my main project is also there,    hope you understand,   


let me know explanation or detailing of any portion that you need to take closer look at; will provide

Comment: currently it is showing 'install package rxJs' in the stackblitz,            @hash-dew